# React Props Is Creating A Empty Div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

So This is the code I am learning from a tutorial and it works but it creates a empty div container I think this is because when I created the props from react I think the h1 and p elements were empty so I think thats why this makes a empty div. Does any one know how to slove this

```
import React from 'react'

function Note(props) {
    return (
        <div className="note">

            <h1>{props.title}</h1>
            <p>{props.content}</p>
            

        </div>
        
        )
}

export default Note
```

Comment: Provide code of your parent component and also check if you are not passing empty props

Comment: Is the div that you see really empty: `<div></div>`? Or does it contain both the `h1` and `p` tags (with no inner text)?

Comment: How do you use that component? If you want it to have a `title` and a `content` prop, you have to provide them (e.g. `<Note title='foo' content='Lorem ipsum dolor sit consequtor amet' />`)

Comment: What values are you passing as a prop from the parent component?